# How to prove uniqueness of approximate "jump" values of an $L^1$ function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, symmetry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $v \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be a unit vector. Given $r>0$, Let $B_r(x)$ be the ball of radius $r$ around $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and define

$$B_r^+(x,v)=\{ y \in B_r(x) \, | \, \langle y-x,v\rangle >0\},$$
and
$$B_r^-(x,v)=\{ y \in B_r(x) \, | \, \langle y-x,v\rangle <0 \}. $$

Now, let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset, and let $u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$.

Let $a \neq b \in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose that

$$
\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{\mu(B_r^+(x,v))}\int_{B_r^+(x,v)}  |u(y)-a|dy=0,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{\mu(B_r^-(x,v))}\int_{B_r^-(x,v)}  |u(y)-b|dy=0.
$$

> **Question:** How to prove that the triple $(a,b,v)$ is uniquely determined up to a permutation of $a$ and $b$, and a change of sign of $v$?

(I stumbled on this fact in a geometric measure theory book- it seems rather plausible, but I don't see an immediate way to prove it).

Comment: If $u=0$, can't you take $a=b=0$ and any $v$?

Comment: You are right. More generally, I think that if $u$ is continuous at $x$, then $a=b=u(x)$ would work for any $v$. This is why it is crucial to require here that $a \neq b$ (as I did).

Comment: Right, I see. I have another dumb question. The limit in the question implies (by triangle inequality) that $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{|B_r(x,v)^+|} \int_{B^+} u = a$$ and similarly for the negative ball with limit $b$. Given that, I don't see how permuting $a$ and $b$ is possible.

Comment: The point is that you permute $a \iff b$ and $v \iff -v$ simultaneously. That is, the claim is that the only possible triples $(\tilde a, \tilde  b,\tilde  v)\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ which satisfy the conditions are $(a,b,v)$ and $(b,a,-v)$. (Of course, the triples $(a,b,v)$ and $(b,a,-v)$ represent the same geometric situation, since $v,-v$ represent the same choice of a "slicing" hyperplane. Your questions are fine, I didn't specify this explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to translation and rescaling, this is a claim about a sequence of functions in $B(0,1)$.  To wit, define $u_{r} : B(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $u_{r}(\xi) = u(x + r \xi)$ to find that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{r \to 0^{+}} \int_{B^{+}_{1}(0,v)} |u_{r}(\xi) - a| \, d \xi = 0, \quad \lim_{r \to 0^{-}} \int_{B^{-}_{1}(0,v)} |u_{r}(\xi) - b| \, d \xi = 0.
\end{equation*}
Now that the domain is no longer moving, this is a question about $L^{1}$-convergence of functions in $B(0,1)$.  In fact, notice that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{r \to 0^{+}} \int_{B_{1}(0)} |u_{r}(\xi) - a \chi_{B_{1}^{+}(0,v)} - b \chi_{B_{1}^{+}(0,v)}| \, d\xi = 0.
\end{equation*}
Since limits in $L^{1}(B(0,1))$ are unique and $a \chi_{B_{1}^{+}(0,v)} + b \chi_{B_{1}^{+}(0,v)}$ uniquely determines $a$, $b$, and $v$ (up to the permutation $(a,b,v) \mapsto (b,a,-v)$), we are done.

Comment: That is a perfect answer, thanks!